# Error installing virtualenvwrapper on MacOS - installation directory and permission issues

Tags: python, virtualenvwrapper, permissionerror

I'm following the installation guides for AutoGPT and it suggests installing Virtualenvwrapper but I seem to always run into walls when working on the terminal of this Mac. Either it's a permission or it does not accept the default cd commands and I need extensive commands to move between folders.

Getting to the issue, after editing the .zshrc file with the 'correct' directory as per `which virtualenvwrapper.sh` I still cannot get any further with the installation. According to the documentation it should be `source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh` but for me it installs under `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh

I have followed these steps:

```
$ sudo pip install virtualenvwrapper
```

**Shell Startup File**

Add three lines to your shell startup file (.bashrc, .profile, etc.) [here I'm not sure if I am doing it right, to access the zshrc file I use `nano .zshrc` to edit] to set the location where the virtual environments should live, the location of your development project directories, and the location of the script installed with this package:

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/Devel
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

By the third line, I get the following error:

```
virtualenvwrapper_run_hook:12: permission denied: 
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks.

If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON= and that PATH is
set properly.
```

After editing it, reload the startup file (e.g., run source ~/.bashrc). -- this does nothing visually.

I read through some of the older posts and I couldn't find these specific issues.

When attempting to run the `mkvirtualenv` command it also says 'not found'